# How to get in JavaScript width and height of image, before it's loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to get sizes (width and height) of an image before it's loaded? Unfortunately I can't use something like this code:

```
$('img').load(function() {
    alert(this.width + ' ' + this.height);
});
```

I can't wait while image is loading, **I need to know sizes of an image at the beggining**.

Is it possible or should I use for example PHP and getimagesize() function and pass it to HTML?

Comment: Why do you need to know the dimensions before the image is loaded? Something tells me there's a better way (like pre-caching the image off-page), but it depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 9):

You can't. The browser doesn't report the dimensions of the image until it's loaded. You'll have to get the information server-side, or change your approach so you don't need to know before it loads.

If you just need to know the size of the image before you put it in the page (rather than literally before you load it), you can do this:

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  // Here, you can reliably use `width` and `height`
  display("Loaded, size is " + this.width + "x" + this.height);
};
img.src = "the/path/to/the/image/goes/here";
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icoyom)

It's important to hook the `load` event *before* setting the `src`, in case the image is in cache and the event fires immediately.

(I don't advocate using DOM0 style handlers like `onload`, but they're useful in quick examples.)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any genuine reason why you can't load your image and then before it is placed in the document to figure out the height. 
You **can wait** until the image has loaded. 
If you can't then you have totally designed your application wrong. (In a non judgmental sort of way :) )

Comment: The quoted code is unreliable. You have to wait for the image to load before you query its size.

Comment: Too many images to show on the screen for a masonry grid layout, so only do the heavy loading when reaching a certain region. Genuine?